# FINDSTR to find text at end of string

Tags: regex, findstr

I have a FINDSTR that looks like this:

```
lots of stuff here | FINDSTR ro.redacted.version.release=
```

it outputs:

```
ro.redacted.version.release=THIS.IS.THE.PART.I.WANT
```

FINDSTR does not play very well with regex, I have tried just about everything that an in-depth Google search throws at me with no luck.
Does any one know a way to get the

THIS.IS.THE.PART.I.WANT

as output instead of

ro.redacted.version.release=THIS.IS.THE.PART.I.WANT

Some background:
This is part of a VBA inside Excel, it opens cmd, uses ADB to pull build version from a phone and then uses that data to do other stuff. Everything else is up and running, so I'd rather not change approach if avoidable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Findstr is a simple 'show the text' program with no way to extract part of a line.

Findstr is also buggy in many ways - there is a good page by dbenham on all the issues.

You can use a `for /F` command to extract parts of the line.  Knowing the exact text in the line up until the part that you want is important - if there is an equals sign between the two parts (and no other equals sign before that) then it's straightforward.

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('findstr "ro.redacted.version.release=" "c:\folder\file.txt" ') do echo "%%b"
```

Comment: Agree with foxdrive.  Findstr won't do what you want.  I'd be inclined to try to get the text into excel and do the regex in there.  You can do the matching of the line with findstr, but then regex in VBA.

Comment: That is the conclusion I came to as well, implementing i tright now and it seems to work fine.